# How to find all the cookies and header fields using a Brython script

Tags: python, brython

How can we find all the cookies and header fields of a HTML document using a Brython script?

I need to find a CSRF_TOKEN from the cookies, I've an alternative way of finding this token but then I have to mention my brython script in HTML, which I don't want to do. I need to put my script in a file, so I need to access the token using DOMNode- "document".

Another related question is how can I find all the elements of DOMNode- "document".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Couldn't find this info on https://brython.info/ . Wish they had a search bar!